# In-App should ask credential whenever i logout from store

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes, in-app-billing

I have query regarding in-app credential.
I have created two sandbox account for eg **accountA** & **accountB** and one package.
I have a video which require subscription to watch. If i click on video it opens the subscription page where we have 'Buy Now' button. On click on we buy a package using accountA and store this package id in NSUserDefaults.

There are two scenario now:

First:

> If **accountA** logout from iTunes store from (Settings->iTunes store) and
>   open the app and click on video it should ask for credential to watch
>   video. (currently the video is playing because we are storing the
>   package id in NSUserDefaults with **irrespective** of user. which i guess
>   its wrong approach). 
>   So i want to test if the **iTunes logged in user** has already purchased that package should not open the subscription page. He/She should directly send to watch video.

Second:

> If **accountB** logged in iTunes Store and open the app. He/She should not
>   able to watch the video until unless does not buy the package for that
>   accountB. or else he has to login with accountA to watch the video
>   which he/she has already purchased.

So my question is how to check whether accountA or accountB has already purchase that package.
I thought to make a restoreTransaction request on every time if he/she clicks on video. But if i do that then every time it opens the dialog to sign-in to iTunes store or alert comes that you have already bought this package and all which i do not want to show to user if he/she has already purchased.

**I do not want to use NSUserDefault to check package has been purchase with some boolean value. I always want to check with the signed-in user.**

> In addition: Can we buy a package for the same installed app with two
>   different account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, We have a method called "- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application" in appDelegate. Write your "Restoring functionality" here. So that it always check that whether the current user( Who logged into iTunes ) has purchased the subscription or not. If the user has purchased the subscription, it will call the "SKPaymentTransactionObserver" delegate method - "(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue" then set your subscription boolean variable "Yes". If user has not purchase the subscription, it calls the "- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error" delegate method, then set your subscription boolean variable "No". Based on this write delegate methods (Or) use NSNOTIFICATIONCENTER to Call the appropriate method i.e if subscritpion == yes allow user to play video 
else 
don't allow the user and show the purchasing subscription options.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this would be to store a variable show the purchased state in NSUserDefaults as I'm sure you are already doing.  However, you can take that a step further and nest all *login related* variables inside NSUserDefaults under a key with the user's username.

Then in your login functionality, just implement a method of loading those NSUserDefaults that are particular to that user and overwrite the current user defaults with those.

```
NSUserDefaults *appDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[appDefaults setObject:[appDefaults objectForKey:@"CURRENT_USERNAME"] forKey:@"current_user"];
[appDefaults synchronize];
```

then when you store the purchase,

```
NSUserDefaults *appDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[appDefaults objectForKey:@"current_user"] setObject:"YES" forKey:@"purchased"];
[[appDefaults objectForKey:@"CURRENT_USERNAME"] setObject:"YES" forKey:@"purchased"];
[appDefaults synchronize];
```

This code is untested but hopefully you'll see the concept.  Just remember to clear the objects for key @"current_user" on logout and again on login prior to loading them from the username key.

"CURRENT_USERNAME" would be replaced with the login name of the current user.

"current_user" would be a generic that you would fill with the current user's specific data sets and purchase info.

hope this helps.

JB